# does rospy support scripting in jython?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to integrate a dialogue classifier in rospy on the NAO robot. I am planning to use the jython script for the stanford nlp parser but i dont know if rospy will support this script. will it?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/96596/does-rospy-support-scripting-in-jython?/) by [uzair](https://answers.ros.org/users/8341/uzair/) on ROS Answers with karma: 87 on 2013-10-31

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You problem is not correctly formulated.

CPython (the classical interpreter) and Jython are two interpreters.
I.e. they both are programs implemented in two different languages.

Compatibility between all interpreters is mainly insured but there are some
slight differences which are listed here:
http://www.jython.org/archive/21/docs/differences.html

In anycase, they both interpret Python files (or modules). As rospy is written in Python you
should be able to use rospy with Jython. Again the best way is to try to import the module
and see what happens.

---

Originally posted by [Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/87/thomas/) with karma: 4478 on 2013-10-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [uzair](https://answers.ros.org/users/8341/uzair/) on 2013-10-31**:
Thank you for the help. I am still struggling tying to download the naoqi sdk. Onc i have everything set up, i will try importing the module.